# How to make an environment same as itembox environment in ascmac package by using mdframed package

Tags: environments, mdframed

I want to make the output same as what I can make from the code shown below. But for some reasons (e.g. some frames extend to multiple pages etc.), I do not want to use `ascmac` package but `mdframed` package. What should I write in the preamble or the option of mdframed environment?

Sorry for my bad English.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\begin{document}
\begin{itembox}[l]{foo}
bar
\end{itembox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Thanks for providing a MWE, but unfortunately it doesn't compile for me. I get `Undefined control sequence.
\@itembox ...\@savetbaselineshift \tbaselineshift 
\tbaselineshift \z@ \par \...
l.4 \begin{itembox}[l]{foo}`, so I don't know the desired output.

Comment: @PeterGrill It seems that the `ascmac` in texlive 2013 produces this error.  The texlive version seems to rather out of date and may be requires the obsolete `platex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach, updated as per your comments.  To get round boxes you need to pass the `tikz` option to `mdframed`.  The title is raised so it hits the bounding box.   As we are using `tikz` anyway, I have put the title in a box that is a `tikz` node with a white background, to overwrite the rule.  We use `innertopmargin` to move the contents up correspondingly, and adjust `innerbottomargin`.

To move this title further right, one option is to make the `tikz` picture a little wider with an invisible extra point, for example via

```
frametitle={\tikz{\path (0,0) (20pt,0) node[anchor=base west,rectangle,fill=white] {\strut #1};}}
```

This will put the title box with its left edge `20pt` further to the right.  Putting it all together we get:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}

\newenvironment{itembox}[1]{\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=10pt,
  frametitlefont=\normalfont,
  frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-0.7\baselineskip,skipabove=\topskip,
  innertopmargin=\dimexpr-0.65\baselineskip,
  innerbottommargin=\dimexpr0.65\baselineskip,
  frametitle={\tikz{\node[anchor=base,rectangle,fill=white] {\strut #1};}}]
}{\end{mdframed}}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{itembox}{foo}
  bar
\end{itembox}

\begin{itembox}{Longer title}
  \lipsum[1-6]
\end{itembox}

\end{document}
```

See the [`mdframed` documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) or `texdoc mdframed` for more parameters to adjust the spacing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is almost exactly what I want, but I want to move the frame title a little to the right. What parameter should I change?

Comment: @Merzong I have updated my answer with this.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, in this way, only the frame title moves upward. There is a white space between the title and the content in the frame. In order to remove this, I wrote `innertopmargin=5pt-\baselineskip` in the preamble but it didn't work. How can I remove this white space and move the content upward?

Comment: @Merzong See my updated answer.

Comment: This is the error that I've found "\DeclareListParser*{\mdf@dolist}{". What version of mdframed package?

Comment: @jeecabz Works OK for me with `mdframed.sty    2013/07/01 1.9b: mdframed`